# iTunes Exclamation Point Error After Clicking "Submitting For Review"

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently finalized the settings for my iTunes connect iPhone app.  It has a watchkit app as well if that matters.   After saving it, I clicked "Submit for Review", and the page only reloads with an exclamation point next to the English selection.  There is no other explanation.  The app appears to be submitted, but I'm curious what this exclamation point means and if something should be resolved or adjusted for it?  It is unclear.

[image]

With Menu expanded:

[image]

Comment: I think you should just ignore it as long as it does not seem to have any kind of influence on your submission to the app store, possibly a bug.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Same here...

Answer (score 3):

I met the similiar situation yesterday, I thought that's result from the iTunes connect update August 8 2016, red exclamation by all localized language without others information.
If you meet this situation from August 8 2016, maybe it's the case.

I contacted Apple support and finally submitted new version until 
I filled up screen-shots for all sizes.

while you can upload the maximum size screenshot and 're-use' it for smaller size at 'Media Manager' page.

Comment: Life saver, thanks!

Just to clarify: You may see the error described on the question if you haven't provided at least one snapshot for every device's size supported. Like Vin says, you may provide screenshots for the bigger size supported and re-use it through the Media Manager page.